# How to install symfony with composer.json?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

when I install symfony with:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

I cannot have other libraries (e.g. zf2) in my project too. so I have to use composer.json

```
require {

             "symfony/framework-standard-edition" : "~2.6"

}
```

but it generates framework-standard-edition within vendor folder, and if I want to move /app/, /web/, /src/ to outside of vendor folder manually, there are some files missing like bootstrap.php.cache, so I was forced to install the project separately with

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

and move its /app/, /web/, /src/ to the location of first installation above.

how is the easiest installation way with composer.json?

Comment: With the composer create-project method, you will be also able to add other dependencies, you just add it to the generated composer.json.

Comment: the Symfony Official Documention Site for create Project using Composer http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#installing-composer-globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally start your project with

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

Then edit the generated composer.json with your other dependencies. So Symfony is your base project.

Comment: Then this is enough to update composer to get other libraries installed?

Comment: Yeah, you just updates your dependencies in composer.json to include any other libraries you would like to use within your Symfony2 project.